# Add group mailbox to sharepoint alerts

Tags: list, alert, library

I would like to set up an alert on my Sharepoint library list. Can we add group mailbox to sharepoint alerts?

Comment: You can Create a custom workflow..I have tried this and working fine for me... Regards,
Sai.N

Answer (score 1):

You can only add alerts to users which has access to the list in question.

One possiblity is to create a dummy user which has been assigned to mailbox address as email and the add an alert to that user.